# List comprehension headaches

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a nested list like this which:

```
list = [[1,2,3], [2,5,7,6], [1,-1], [5,7], [6,3,7,4,3], [2, 5, 1, -5]]
```

What I am trying to do is to remove nested lists, where the value within these lists are both positive and negative. I have tried doing it by list comprehension, but I couldn't figure it out.

```
def method(list):
    return [obj for obj in list if (x for x in obj if -x not in obj)]
```

The obtained results should be like:

```
 list = [[1,2,3], [2,5,7,6], [5,7], [6,3,7,4,3]]
```

Comment: How would `[1, -2]` be treated?

Comment: don't override defaults, use my_list instead of list

Comment: Can you perform a test on each sub-list which keeps only lists where the sum of absolute values equals the actual sum?

Comment: @Andy ````[1, -2]```` would be treated different. Only the values that have counter parts are affected.

Comment: Then the answer that you marked as accepted does not works as expected

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you want lists where elements are either all negative or all positive you can use `all` predefined function to check for both possibilities

```
result = [L for L in x if all(y>0 for y in L) or all(y<0 for y in L)]
```

EDIT:

In the comments you clarified what is a valid list (e.g. `[-1, 2]` is valid)... with this new formulation the test should be

```
result = [L for L in x if all(-y not in L for y in L)]
```

where each single test is however now quadratic in the size of the list. Using `set` this problem can be removed

```
result = [L for L in x if all(-y not in S for S in (set(L),) for y in L)]
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me :)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question as clarified in the comments, though. This approach would remove `[1, -2]`, which is undesired behavior.

Comment: @Andy: you're right, I've edited the answer to handle this more complex test

Answer (score 3):

Using list comprehension you can do something like:

```
def method2(list):
    return [obj for obj in list if (all(n>0 for n in obj) or all(n<0 for n in obj))]
```

that, with your example, give as output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 5, 7, 6], [5, 7], [6, 3, 7, 4, 3]]
```

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense and I up-voted your answer. Now I know why it wasn't working on my end.

Answer (score 2):

In general is better to split the task by steps:

1. Given list find the positives (`positives` function)
2. Given list find the negatives and multiply them by -1 (`negatives` function)
3. If the intersection of both positives and negatives is not empty remove.

So, you could do:

```
def positives(ls):
    return set(l for l in ls if l > 0)


def negatives(ls):
    return set(-1*l for l in ls if l < 0)


list = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 5, 7, 6], [1, -1], [5, 7], [6, 3, 7, 4, 3], [2, 5, 1, -5]]
result = [l for l in list if not negatives(l) & positives(l)]

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 5, 7, 6], [5, 7], [6, 3, 7, 4, 3]]
```

As a side note you should not use list as a variable name as it shadows the built-int list function.

Answer (score 2):

Your generator should yield whether the condition to filter an object applies.
You then feed the generator to an aggregator to determine if obj should be filtered.
the aggregator could be any or all, or something different.

```
# assuming obj should be filtered if both x and the inverse of x are in obj
def method_with_all(src):
    return [obj for obj in src if all(-x not in obj for x in obj)]

def method_with_any(src):
    return [obj for obj in src if any(-x in obj for x in obj)]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can filter out the lists that have both negative and positive elements:

```
def keep_list(nested_list):

    is_first_positive = nested_list[0] > 0

    for element in nested_list[1:]:
        if (element > 0) != is_first_positive:
            return False

    return True


my_list = [[1,2,3], [2,5,7,6], [1,-1], [5,7], [6,3,7,4,3], [2, 5, 1, -5]]

print(list(filter(keep_list, my_list)))
```

output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 5, 7, 6], [5, 7], [6, 3, 7, 4, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Numpy can be used as well. My solution here is similar to the "all"-operation suggested by others but coded explicitly and only needs one condition. It checks whether the sign of the all the elements equals the sign of the first element (could be any other as well).

```
from numpy import *    

def f(b): 
   return [a for a in b if sum(sign(array(a)) == sign(a[0])) == len(a)]
```

For your case...

```
data = [[1,2,3], [2,5,7,6], [1,-1], [5,7], [6,3,7,4,3], [2, 5, 1, -5]]
print(f(data))
```

...it will return:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 5, 7, 6], [5, 7], [6, 3, 7, 4, 3]]
```